# Get the Inner Array Value of JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need the basic Help , I have a json object in the following format

```
Data = {"line":"1",
        "column":"1"
        "response":[{"criteria":"starts","response":"358","field":"S"},
                {"criteria":"ends","response":"359","field":"H"}]}
```

I can get the Line and Column value as below

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);             
var line = obj['line'];
var column=obj['column'];
```

I have tried below format but i cannt get response value:

```
var res = new Array(obj['response']);
alert(res[0]['criteria']);
```

And

```
var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(obj['response']);
var innerArray = jsonObject['response'];
alert(innerArray[0].fieldvalue);
```

how can i get the values in obj['response'] ? Any one could help me to find the solution

Comment: Try `console.log(obj);`

Comment: `Data.response` or `Data['response']` should be the array.

Comment: `obj['response'][0] ` ??

Comment: Can not try it here, but how about Data['response']['criteria']

Comment: what's the result of `obj.response[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to create a new array?

```
var res = new Array(obj['response']);
alert(res[0]['criteria']);
```

It is already converted to an array after you parse the JSON string, so this will work:

```
var res = obj['response'];
alert(res[0]['criteria']);
```